# Legend of Zelda Skyward Sword Silent Realm Skyloft Secret Area?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

It's bugged me for a long time now, that in the silent realm of Skyloft, also known as the Goddess's Silent Realm, on the map, there's an area you cannot access, which is where the goddess statue is. My question is if there's anyway to get there, normally or with a glitch/bug (no hacks) and if there's any secret item or something up there?

Comment: What do you mean glitch but no hacks? Like, without literally editing Link's position with external tools?

Comment: @Union Well, by glitches I mean something you can do but isn't intentional of the designer (for example if you could stick a camera in a corner of the wall and see through them (only applicable for some games)) by hacks I mean using an external tool or software to virtually change how the game works.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a map of the area from IGN:
[image: Goddess's Silent Realm map]

According to it, the entire Goddess Statue subarea is out-of-bounds, and there's no secret Dusk Relics located there (the only collectible found in Silent Realms). So even if there were a way to sneak your way over there (which I haven't heard of anyone successfully doing), there's nothing to be found.

Comment: When I said secret item, I didn't nessecarily mean dusk relics, perhaps there's something more top secret? Even if there's no one who's done it, or no items, my question is if it's possible. I'd like to go there.

Comment: What if I did open it up to exploits?

Comment: Given that you're not supposed to be over there, either there won't be anything special to be found, or the area won't even have any collision and you'll just fall through everything. I suspect someone has already tried it but I wouldn't know where to look.